# delete element with firebug on mac

Tags: macos, firebug

In Windows, Firebug -> Inspect, I can click on an element and delete it with the delete key.

In a Mac (using the [small wireless keyb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aApple-wireless-keyboard-aluminum-2007.jpg)) I can't delete or fn+delete it.  Can someone tell me how that can be done please?

Comment: This keyboard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Firebug key assignment on the Mac? It may be that it needs to 'learn' the key combination of <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

See this link: http://theandystratton.com/2009/how-to-change-firebug-shortcut-in-firefox-mac-os-x

Comment: Thank you JYelton, it appears that can't be done in Firebug-Lite for Chrome.  Trying it in FF works well. BTW what's the markup for the fn+delete you used in the answer?

Comment: It is kbd in angle braces. It's not listed here (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) but the link may be of help anyway.